# Deleting specific control characters(\n \r \t) from a string

Tags: python, string

I have quite large amount of text which include control charachters like \n \t and \r.
I need to replace them with a simple space--> " ". What is the fastest way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Obviously, as Zen of Python suggests, there is only way to do that ;-)

Comment: when the string has multiple adjacent such characters e.g.`foo\r\nbar`, do you want to replace `\r\n` by two spaces or only 1?

Comment: i want to replace it with only 1

Comment: Consider also stripping leading and trailing whitespace. Then please edit your question so that it specifies exactly what you want.

Comment: If you want to strip leading and trailing whitespace as well, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898656/remove-whitespace-in-python-using-string-whitespace/1898835#1898835).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think the fastest way is to use `str.translate()`:

```
import string
s = "a\nb\rc\td"
print s.translate(string.maketrans("\n\t\r", "   "))
```

prints

```
a b c d
```

**EDIT**: As this once again turned into a discussion about performance, here some numbers.  For long strings, `translate()` is *way* faster than using regular expressions:

```
s = "a\nb\rc\td " * 1250000

regex = re.compile(r'[\n\r\t]')
%timeit t = regex.sub(" ", s)
# 1 loops, best of 3: 1.19 s per loop

table = string.maketrans("\n\t\r", "   ")
%timeit s.translate(table)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 29.3 ms per loop
```

That's about a factor 40.

Comment: It is important to note that string.translate and string.makestrans is not available in Python3. re based solution seems better.

Comment: @Ignacio: import string;hasattr(string,'translate');hasattr(string,'maketrans') It will be False, if you do hasattr(str,'translate') and hasattr(str,'maketrans') it is True. module string is just a collection of string constants. Moreover, as per definition and proper way to use maketrans would be bytes.maketrans. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You may also try regular expressions:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'[\n\r\t]')
regex.sub(' ', my_str)
```

Comment: I've compared the actual performance and it looks like using regular expressions is as fast as using the string module.

Comment: `python2.6 timeit.py -s "import string" -s "s = 'a\nb\rc\td'" -s "s.translate(string.maketrans('\n\t\r', '   '))"`
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0235 usec per loop

Comment: `python2.6 timeit.py -s "import re" -s "regex = re.compile(r'[\n\r\t]')" -s "regex.sub(' ', 'a\nb\rc\td')"`
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0232 usec per loop

Comment: @Michal - are you comparing `regex.sub(...)` to `s.translate(string.maketrans(...))` or to `s.translate(preparedTrans)` only?

Comment: @eumiro, the former, my bad - I focused on the above solution. The latter is comparable, though.

Comment: `python2.6 timeit.py -s "import string" -s "s = 'a\nb\rc\td'" -s "trans = string.maketrans('\n\t\r', '   ')" -s "s.translate(trans)"`
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0256 usec per loop

Comment: @Michal: It's completely meaningless to try this on a string with 7 characters.  See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> re.sub(r'[\t\n\r]', ' ', '1\n2\r3\t4')
'1 2 3 4'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to normalise whitespace (replace runs of one or more whitespace characters by a single space, and strip leading and trailing whitespace) this can be accomplished by using string methods:

```
>>> text = '   foo\tbar\r\nFred  Nurke\t Joe Smith\n\n'
>>> ' '.join(text.split())
'foo bar Fred Nurke Joe Smith'
```

Answer (score 2):

using regex

```
re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', '1\n2\r3\t4')
```

without regex

```
>>> ' '.join('1\n\n2\r3\t4'.split())
'1 2 3 4'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`my_string` is the string where you want to delete specific control characters.
As strings are immutable in python, after substitute operation you need to assign it to another string or reassign it:

```
my_string = re.sub(r'[\n\r\t]*', '', my_string)
```