# How to remove new line and linefeed from title tags of a page? (Google App Engine - Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, beautifulsoup, urllib

I have this code to extract title:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url))
title = str(soup.html.head.title.string).lstrip("\r\n").rstrip("\r\n")
```

Some sites add return or newline before and after title tags (why?) and to remove them I added

```
.lstrip("\r\n").rstrip("\r\n")
```

This works for instance with http://www.readwriteweb.com/ but not with http://poundwire.com/. Can you tell why one is working and the other is not?

**Update**

Following up on comment by Steve Jessop; I'm using `replace` and it seems to work:

```
title = str(soup.html.head.title.string).replace("\t", "").replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")
```

Let me know if there is a better way. Thanks.

**Update 2**

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898656/remove-whitespace-in-python-using-string-whitespace/1898835#1898835) and it seems better:

```
title = " ".join(str(soup.html.head.title.string).split())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `str(title).strip()` which will trim all whitespace from the start and end of the string.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case white space is not causing the error, so I am doing: `>>> k.strip("\t\r\n")
'    PoundWire - Read and share your daily news by topic'` There is still space in front but tab and new lines are stripped.

Answer (score 1):

On poundwire, there's a tab character inside the `<title>` tag. There are also some spaces (the indenting that you'll probably see if you "view source") which you probably want removed too.

Like samplebias says, use `strip()` to remove whitespace at both ends of the string. And get a text editor with a "visible whitespace" mode, switch that mode on, and never turn it off again, ever :-)

Btw, if you're on Google App Engine that means you're on Python 2.5, which in turn means `str` is a non-Unicode string type. BeautifulSoup goes to some lengths to coerce its input into Unicode, so it seems a shame to throw an exception when you hit a page whose title contains non-ASCII characters.

[Edit: third case

```
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun 12 2010, 17:07:01)
[GCC 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen('http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/'))
>>> soup.html.head.title.string
u'\\n google-refine -\\n \\n \\n Google Refine, a power tool for working with messy data (formerly Freebase Gridworks) - Google Project Hosting\\n '
>>>
```

So, the space right at the end means that your `rstrip` doesn't remove the `\n` near the end.

Comment: I am using notepad++ which has visible whitespace mode but I don't keep it on.

Comment: @Zeynel: I turned it on about 8 years ago, and kept it. Just make sure the dot for spaces is faint enough with your monitor's contrast settings, that it's not intrusive in ordinary text. You still see it when there's a bunch of them together, or at the ends of lines, and those are where it's most mischievous when processing text.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: regarding your edit, I am still confused about the unicode in python and especially about `str`. Am I not using it properly here? Is this why I need to do `title = unicode(title, "utf-8"))` later when I write `title` to the database?

Comment: @Zeynel: the basic design of `str` vs `unicode` isn't very good, that's why it changes in Python 3. Basically `str` is a sequence of bytes, whereas `unicode` is a sequence of (Unicode BMP) characters. It just so happens that with ASCII data, a sequence of bytes is capable of representing an equal number of characters. BeautifulSoup returns `unicode` data, which you convert to `str`, then manipulated, then converted back to `unicode` for the db. You might as well just manipulate it as `unicode`. Try this: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Great, thank you for the link. Going back to the original issue I got the same error with this page: `http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/` It appears that they only have newlines and my code is `            title = str(soup.html.head.title.string).lstrip("\t\r\n").rstrip("\t\r\n")` which works otherwise but not with this. In Notepad++ I see `CR LF` but IDLE shows only `\n`. How can I handle this case?

Comment: @Zeynel: I'll edit the answer to mention that, the code I want to show won't fit in a comment

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Thanks. I edited my question. Now I am using `title = " ".join(str(soup.html.head.title.string).split())` and it seems to work.