# How to remove all the white space from string in Python

Tags: python, string, whitespace

I get a string from XML likebelow:

```
This is the                                     Sample text I need to get       
all this               but only with single spaces
```

Actually I am using the following reg-ex which is converting matching pattern to white space but I need them to be stripped not replaced by white space.

The above string should be output:

> This is the Sample text I need to get all this but only with single spaces

Comment: You forgot to include the regex. Anyway, what do you mean by replacing white-space by white-space ? Is it: "I want to aggregate all white-space sequences to a single white-space" ?

Comment: Why not to use search? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898656/remove-whitespace-in-python-using-string-whitespace

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple solution without regex:

```
s = 'This is the                                     Sample text I need to get       all this               but only with single spaces'
' '.join(s.split())
#'This is the Sample text I need to get all this but only with single spaces'
```

For completeness I'll add ekhumoro's comment to my answer:

> It's worth pointing out that split() does more than simply splitting
>   on runs of whitespace: it also strips any whitespace at the beginning
>   and end of the input (which is usually what is wanted). It also
>   correctly handles non-breaking spaces if the input is unicode (which
>   will probably be relevant for XML).

Comment: But why not " ".join(s.split())?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `split()` does more than simply splitting on runs of whitespace: it also strips any whitespace at the beginning and end of the input (which is usually what is wanted). It also correctly handles non-breaking spaces if the input is unicode (which will probably be relevant for XML).