# How to use multiple delimiters when using csv.reader in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple lines of texts in a text file that look similar to this:

```
2012-03-16 13:47:30.465 -0400   START  Running    Lab.script    19    on_the
```

I want to be able to convert this text file into csv. I've already done that using this code:

```
fin = csv.reader(open('LogFile.txt', 'rb'), delimiter='\t')
fout = open('newLogFile.csv', 'w')
for row in fin:
   fout.write(','.join(row) + '\n')
```

But now, my issue is that I need to be able to add a "," after the spaces in this part of the line:

```
2012-03-16 13:47:30.465 -0400
```

I'm not sure how to do it, I've tried using split(), to split the current row/position but it didn't work. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would helpful to instead just tab delimit everything from the beginning? If so you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1898835/322909), essentially

> There is a special-case shortcut for exactly this use case!
>
> If you call str.split without an argument, it splits on runs of
>   whitespace instead of single characters. So:
>
> ```
> >>> ' '.join("Please \n don't \t hurt \x0b me.".split()) 
> "Please don't hurt me."
> ```

so for you it would be

```
newLogFile = open('newLogFile.csv', 'w')
textFile = open('LogFile.txt', 'rb')
for row in textFile:
    newLogFile.write('\t'.join(row.split()))
```

Also you said

> But now, my issue is that I need to be able to add a "," after the
>   spaces in this part of the line:
>
> 2012-03-16 13:47:30.465 -0400

to me that sounds like you want

```
2012-03-16 ,13:47:30.465 ,-0400
```

Comment: Both the answers were good, but yours solved my second issue where I couldn't read the file as csv.reader() after I configured it originally. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
fin = csv.reader(open('LogFile.txt', 'rb'), delimiter='\t')
fout = open('newLogFile.csv', 'w')
for row in fin:
   row[0] = ','.join(row[0].split())
   fout.write(','.join(row) + '\n')
```

This will take a row that looks like this after being read in by `csv.reader()`:

```
['2012-03-16 13:47:30.465 -0400', 'START', 'Running', 'Lab.script', '19 ', 'on_the']
```

And then change the first element so that it looks like this:

```
['2012-03-16,13:47:30.465,-0400', 'START', 'Running', 'Lab.script', '19 ', 'on_the']
```

And after `','.join()` on the row you get the line that will be written to your output file:

```
'2012-03-16,13:47:30.465,-0400,START,Running,Lab.script,19,on_the'
```

If there are other elements that may have spaces in them and you want to treat them all as a delimiter in your output csv, you can do the following:

```
fin = csv.reader(open('LogFile.txt', 'rb'), delimiter='\t')
fout = open('newLogFile.csv', 'w')
for row in fin:
   fout.write(','.join(','.join(item.split()) for item in row) + '\n')
```

Comment: Hi, I was trying to use csv.reader() after the whole writing process, and everytime I do "for row in csv.reader(): print row[some value]", it will only print for row[0], otherwise it gives me an error saying the list is out of range. I also set the delimiter to "\t", and it still gave me that error..