# Pass regex to delimiter field in python's csv module or numpy's genfromtxt / loadtxt?

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have tabulated data with some strange delimination (i.e. groups of values separated by commas, seperated from other values by tabs):

```
A,345,567   56  67  test
```

Is there a clean and clever way of handling multiple delimiters in any of the following: [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), [numpy.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), or [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)?

I have found methods [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745572/how-to-use-multiple-delimiters-when-using-csv-reader-in-python?rq=1), but I'm hoping there is a better solution out there. Ideally I'd like to use a genfromtxt and a regex for the delimiter.

Comment: Will using both tab and `,` as delimiter work? Check your data if it should be delimited by tab first or comma first, or anything goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m afraid the answer is *no* in the three packages you asked for.  However, you can just do `replace('\t', ',')` (or the reverse).  For example:

```
from StringIO import StringIO # py3k: from io import StringIO
import csv
with open('./file') as fh:
    io = StringIO(fh.read().replace('\t', ','))

reader = csv.reader(io)

for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there another package that allows this functionality, preferably with a numpy array as output? I found another that has been sugested ([asciitable](http://cxc.harvard.edu/contrib/asciitable/)), but it also appears to not support such a thing.

Comment: This is assuming that `,` and `\t` are equivalent. Then again, only the OP knows whether they are actually equivalent or not.

Comment: In this particular case I am working on, they are equivalent. Is this approach resource intensive, though?

Comment: @shootingstars: you can use [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html); `pandas` has quickly become one of the most useful Python tools for data munging.  It accepts regex delimiters; I've used them myself.  And you can easily convert pandas `DataFrames` to `ndarray`s.

Comment: @DSM I have yet to look into `pandas`, despite a couple of other suggestions, but this would be another great reason for me to try it out.

Comment: @shootingstars Right from the docs you linked: `data = numpy.loadtxt(io)` or `data = numpy.genfromtxt(io)` in place of the `reader = ` line.

Comment: @Kwpolska Sorry, I mean another that supports regex input such as DSM mentioned. Perhaps you're saying this is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old questions, but numpy now has [`numpy.fromregex`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromregex.html), which should handle this.

From my example provided, an almost working example would be:

```py
>>> with TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:
...     fp_csv = Path(tmp_dir, "temp.csv")
...     with fp_csv.open("w") as fh:
...         fh.write("A,345,567   56  67  test")
...         fh.write("B,345,567   56  67  test")
...     a = np.fromregex(str(fp_csv), r"([a-zA-Z\d.]+)|(\r\n|\n)", dtype="S3")
array([[b'A', b''],
       [b'345', b''],
       [b'567', b''],
       [b'56', b''],
       [b'67', b''],
       [b'tes', b''],
       [b'345', b''],
       [b'567', b''],
       [b'56', b''],
       [b'67', b''],
       [b'tes', b'']], dtype='|S3')
```