# How to check for white space input in python

Tags: python, file-io

I'm very new to programming and python. I'm writing a script and I want to exit the script if the customer type a white space. 
questions is how do I do it right? 
This is my attempt but I think is wrong

For example

```
userType = raw_input('Please enter the phrase to look: ')
userType = userType.strip()

line = inf.readline()
while (userType == raw_input)
    print "userType\n"

    if (userType == "")
        print "invalid entry, the program will terminate"
        # some code to close the app
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but this may help someone in the future. I figured out how to do this with regex. Here is my code:

```
import re

command = raw_input("Enter command :")

if re.search(r'[\s]', command):
    print "No spaces please."
else:
    print "Do your thing!"
```

Answer (score 2):

The program you provided is not a valid python program.  Because you are a beginner some small changes to you program. This should run and does what I understood what it should be.

This is only a starting point: the structure is not clear and you have to change things as you need them.

```
userType = raw_input('Please enter the phrase to look: ')
userType = userType.strip()

#line = inf.readline() <-- never used??
while True:
    userType = raw_input()
    print("userType [%s]" % userType)

    if userType.isspace():
        print "invalid entry, the program will terminate"
        # some code to close the app
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

After applying strip to remove whitespace, use this instead:

```
if not len(userType):
     # do something with userType
else:
     # nothing was entered
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [strip all whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898656/remove-whitespace-in-python-using-string-whitespace) in your input and check if anything is left.

```
import string

userType = raw_input('Please enter the phrase to look: ')
if not userType.translate(string.maketrans('',''),string.whitespace).strip():
      # proceed with your program
      # Your userType is unchanged.
else:
      # just whitespace, you could exit.
```